# Stored Proc Logical Reads Spiking Daily At The Same Time

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, random, parameter-sniffing, query-performance

I have a procedure that I optimized in a dev environment.  It is a heavy lifter and started at 14 millions logical reads with a run time of 30-40 seconds.  I got it down to 96k reads and 8 seconds.  It was pushed to our production database.  Then we noticed that for the last 3 days from 11:30AM-2PM the performance for this proc was tanking with the run time going anywhere from 40 seconds to 2 minutes and the logical read count jumping to 12 million.

This same query on this same server and DB goes back to 70-95k reads and a couple of seconds around 3PM.

This issue CANNOT be reproduced in the dev or QA environments and the schema structure is the same between them all and prod.

At first I thought sniffing or a bad execution plan but that doesnt explain the consistent timing aspect of it all.

I cant tell if I am over looking something that is staring me in the face or if there is more to the story.  What could cause this read spike?  Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Is perhaps something else is going on in your environment at that time? Is the data changing in the tables? Is the plan being flushed from cache due to a lot of other activity, and a less effective plan being chosen? Do batch requests per second change during that time? How is memory?

Comment: I need to coordinate with our Sr DBA to monitor IO and memory during that time frame but I dont think the execution plans are to blame.  When you run the contents of the proc separately during this time reads for the query are normal.  That got me thinking that it could be a bad plan but that wouldnt explain the randomness of it all.  

I am investigating any other processes that are running behind the scenes that could impact this procs performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root was tracked to some old SSIS packages running longer than anticipated. Thanks for the feedback folks!

Comment: @JackDouglas not sure why you would think it was a "typo in the code" but the code works through out most of the day and then DB performance for this procedure tanks during a set time frame. I figured reaching out to other DBAs could help shed light on potential bottlenecks or possible interference with SSIS packages in the background that could impede performance.   I would disagree that it is too localized since over all server and DB performance is what we focus on.